# Difference between IBM Watson Conversation and Natural Language Classifier?

Tags: nlp, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

What is difference between IBM Watson Conversation and Natural Language Classifier?

Conversation: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation.html

Natural Language Classifier:https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/natural-language-classifier/

Answer (score 6):

The Natural Language Classifier service supports classification-only use cases (for example, routing calls in a call center). Watson Conversation includes similar intents, but also helps you to build and train a bot with entities and dialog to simulate conversation.

Both services have a graphical UI available. However, the Conversation UI tool offers more features.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, Conversation provides you with an UI and functionality to wire up all the things you would have to do manually with Natural Language Classifier.  Within Conversation, you also have the ability to create dialog/conversational workflow based on your defined intents and entities which you can create within the same UI.

Comment: Thank you for reply